# python dict's key elements select and create new dict from values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like the one below. i need to separate this dictionary but i couldn't succeed somehow

Logically, there are 2 vehicles and 3 routes. There are 13 customers in total. Each customer is visited once. Customer 5 and 6 do not receive service. In the first dictionary I gave, there are the roads that the vehicle-route pairs go. What I want is to separate each vehicle on the way it goes, and secondly, separate each vehicle for the customers it goes to

```
       routes = {(1, 3): [[0, 1], [1, 8], [8, 9], [9, 12], [12, 13]], 
                 (1, 2): [[0, 2], [2, 13]], 
                 (2, 2): [[0, 3], [3, 11], [11, 13]], 
                 (2, 1): [[0, 4], [4, 13]], 
                 (2, 3): [[0, 7], [7, 13]], 
                 (1, 1): [[0, 10], [10, 13]]}
```

I need to get 2 separate datasets from this dictionary.
The first one takes the dictionary keys first element and I will create the following dictionary

```
     car_trips= {1: [[0, 1], [1, 8], [8, 9], [9, 12], [12, 13],[0, 10], [10, 13],[0, 2], [2, 13]],
                 2: [[0, 3], [3, 11], [11, 13] , [0, 4], [4, 13], [0, 7], [7, 13]]
```

The second one takes the dictionary keys first element and values second elements I will create the following dictionary, values not repetable

```
      car_customers= {1: [0,1,8,9,12,10,2,13]
                      2: [0,3,11,4,7,13]}
```

i hope i could explain, Thank you from now

Comment: Your sample output requirement (car_customers) doesn't contain the value 2. What logic excludes that?

Comment: What have you done so far? You sample data has incorrect value too

Comment: Your output from car_customers doesn't make sense to the logic you explained in text, please cross verify it.

Comment: Why the title refers to _dict sort_?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to convert the routes dictionary to the car_trips dictionary.

```
car_trips = {}

for key, value in routes.items():

    if key[0] in car_trips:
        car_trips[key[0]] += value
    else:
        car_trips[key[0]] = value
```

I can't make the other function due to your incorrect example data

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
car_trips = dict()
car_customers = dict()

routes = {(1, 3): [[0, 1], [1, 8], [8, 9], [9, 12], [12, 13]],
          (1, 2): [[0, 2], [2, 13]],
          (2, 2): [[0, 3], [3, 11], [11, 13]],
          (2, 1): [[0, 4], [4, 13]],
          (2, 3): [[0, 7], [7, 13]],
          (1, 1): [[0, 10], [10, 13]]}

for (k, *_), v in routes.items():
    car_trips.setdefault(k, list()).__iadd__(v)
    car_customers.setdefault(k, set()).__ior__({e for _, e in v})

car_customers = {k: list(v) for k, v in car_customers.items()}

print(car_trips)
print(car_customers)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: [[0, 1], [1, 8], [8, 9], [9, 12], [12, 13], [0, 2], [2, 13], [0, 10], [10, 13]], 2: [[0, 3], [3, 11], [11, 13], [0, 4], [4, 13], [0, 7], [7, 13]]}
{1: [1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13], 2: [3, 4, 7, 11, 13]}
```